# NSIS: Unable to read long registry (string) values

Tags: registry, nsis

[EDIT] The problem was that the string data in the registry entry was too long for NSIS to read it. Manually shortening the string solved it. Obviously, the new problem is how to read long string values from registry...

I'm trying to read the whitelist of ffdshow from registry. I've located the specific registry entry, it's in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\GNU\ffdshow. It's a very long list of applications.

[image]

I try to read the registry entry like this:

```
ReadRegStr $R0 HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\GNU\ffdshow" "whitelist"
DetailPrint "Values: $R0"
```

Unfortunately, R0 appears to be an empty string.

[image]

As said, shorting the whitelist string solved the problem, but how can I retrieve such a long string? I would like to append my application to the list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIS is by default available with an internal string length of 1024 bytes.
If the string that you read is longer than 1024 bytes, it might be truncated or nullified because its buffer is too short for the registry query.

One solution is to use a NSIS version that is compiled with a longer string length. Such a version with 8k strings is available from the [Special builds](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds) page of NSIS. You can also recompile it yourself if you need some other build-time settings.

Comment: It works! The download contains both makensis.exe and a bunch of "Stubs". Both have to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Using the NSIS long string build is a stopgap solution, what do you do when the string exceeds that limit as well? Sadly NSIS does not have good support for strings longer than the internal string limit and your only option is to call native Windows functions or write a custom plugin that handles your task.

Just reading the string is hard and this is before we even think about parsing it:

```
#define STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ 0x00020000
!define KEY_QUERY_VALUE 0x0001
!define SRRF_RT_REG_SZ 2
!include WinCore.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Function RegReadValueString
Exch $2
Exch 
Exch $1
Push $3
Push $4
Push $5
Push $6
Push $0
StrCpy $3 0
loop:
    System::Call 'shlwapi::SHRegGetValue(i$1,i0,tr2,i${SRRF_RT_REG_SZ},*i.r4,i0,*i0r5)i.r0' ; Note: This function is XP.SP2+, use RegQueryValueEx + real \0 termination on older systems
    StrCpy $6 $5
    ${IfThen} $4 <> ${REG_SZ} ${|} Goto error ${|}
    System::Alloc $5
    Pop $3
    ${IfThen} $3 = 0 ${|} Goto done ${|}
    System::Call 'shlwapi::SHRegGetValue(i$1,i0,tr2,i${SRRF_RT_REG_SZ},*i.r4,ir3,*ir5r5)i.r0'
    ${If} $4 = ${REG_SZ}
    ${AndIf} $0 = 0
    ${AndIf} $5 U<= $6
        Goto done
    ${EndIf}
error:
    System::Free $3
    StrCpy $3 0
done:
    ${IfThen} $5 U> $6 ${|} Goto loop ${|}
Pop $0
Pop $6
Pop $5
Pop $4
Exch $3
Exch 2
Pop $2
Pop $1
FunctionEnd

Section
System::Call 'advapi32::RegOpenKeyEx(i${HKEY_CURRENT_USER},t"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs",i0,i${STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ}|${KEY_QUERY_VALUE},*i0r1)i.r0'
${If} $0 = 0
    Push $1
    Push "url1"
    Call RegReadValueString
    Pop $2
    ${If} $2 <> 0
        System::Call 'user32::MessageBox(i$hwndparent,i$2,t"The value:",i0)'
        System::Free $2
    ${EndIf}
    System::Call 'advapi32::RegCloseKey(i$1)'
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```